# Get Ip address of computes nodes in an openstack network

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I planned to create a service that sleeps/wakes unused compute nodes in an openstack environment for that i need an ip address of the compute nodes.
Is there any API or command available to get IP address( not the name of the compute node )machines present in the openstack network?

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of IP addresses used in OpenStack cloud environment setup.

1. Fixed:

   Accessed only from the openstack network, That is among VMs.
2. Floating :

   Could be accessed from outside the OpenStack cloud network, basically works on a different interface, and generally this IP is made available to public to access this VM from outside netwrok.

Now, you know this, follow the API given here.
http://api.openstack.org/api-ref.html#ext-os-ext-ips

While getting IP address through the JSON response, first you have to check whether it is fixed or floating.

That should answer your question, I hope. If not then please inform.

Comment: Fixed and Floating IPs are assigned to the instances that are created, what i need is the Ip of the host i.e compute node that runs those instances.

Comment: http://api.openstack.org/api-ref.html#identity-v2.0 . make a POST request to "v2.0/tokens" and it should return JSON containing service catalog. Find in service catalog field "type":"compute" and you will get the public URL of compute module. Instances run on this public URL of compute.(generally)

Answer (score 0):

You can query the nova database and get the ip of all the compute nodes in the compute_node tables. I wrote a small function in python to do this for one of my tests.

```
def get_compute_nodes(parameters):
    try:
        password = parameters['password']
        db=_mysql.connect(user="root",passwd=password, db="nova")
        query = """select host_ip from compute_nodes where deleted=0"""
        db.query(query)
        r=db.use_result()
        results =  r.fetch_row(maxrows=0)
        return results
    except Exception as exp:
        print "Error in accessing the Nova database"
        print exp
```

Comment: Hi, is there a "official way" how to query the database? I mean, the Nova Conductor handles all database requests and nothing should go directly to the database, right?

Comment: Hi! No, unfortunately there is no "official way" recommended by the OpenStack to query the DB. They have exposed the APIs so that users don't have to query the DB. You can also use the OpenStack Python SDK but at the moment the method just returns the name of the compute. So the method has to be modified in opinion or you can write a new one calling the REST API. You can use httplib library in python to do that. I will try to write and and add it as an answer.